# Gulp watch delete files

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm new to Gulp, i did some research but not found solutions .. Here is my Gulpfile.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


var paths = {
    src: 'src/',
    dist: 'dist/',
    html: '**/*.html',
    php: '**/*.php',
    images: {
        src: 'assets/img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg,gif}',
        dist: 'assets/img'
    },
    misc: '**/*.{ico,htaccess,txt}'
}


/**
 * Files
 */
gulp.task('files', function(){

    return gulp.src([
        paths.src + paths.php,
        paths.src + paths.html,
        paths.src + paths.misc
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

/**
 * Images
 */
gulp.task('images', function(){

    return gulp.src(
        paths.src + paths.images.src
    )
    .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + paths.images.dist))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

/**
 * Serve
 */
gulp.task('serve', ['files', 'images'], function(){

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });

    watch([
        paths.src + paths.php,
        paths.src + paths.html,
        paths.src + paths.misc
    ], function(){ gulp.start('files') }); 


    watch(
        paths.src + paths.images.src
    , function(){ gulp.start('images') }); 

});
```

All is ok but during watching files from my "src" folder (serve task), when i delete a file (image or html,php etc...) in "src", the file is not deleted in the "dist" folder.

When file changed or added, no problem.. I've found some similar topics but not the solution..

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The reason files aren't deleted in your `dist` folder is because `gulp.watch()` simply reruns a task whenever a watched file changes. That task doesn't know that the reason it is running is because a file was deleted. It simply processes all files matching the glob in its `gulp.src()` statement.

Since the deleted file doesn't exist anymore, it is not picked up by `gulp.src()` and your task doesn't process it. It is simply left standing as it is in your `dist` folder, while the other files there are overwritten.

One way to fix this is to follow the [Handling the Delete Event on Watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/handling-the-delete-event-on-watch.md) recipe:

```
var fileWatcher = watch([
    paths.src + paths.php,
    paths.src + paths.html,
    paths.src + paths.misc
], function(){ gulp.start('files') }); 

fileWatcher.on('change', function (event) {
    if (event.type === 'deleted') {
        var filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve(paths.src), event.path);
        var destFilePath = path.resolve(paths.dist, filePathFromSrc);
        del.sync(destFilePath);
    }
});
```

The handling for your images would be analogous.

Comment: Thanks Sven, it's ok :)

Comment: Just a note that the link above provided by Sven has a small error as of mid-August 2018. It shows a recipe with `unlink` instead of `change`. Stick with `change` as you see in Sven's answer and you'll be good. The API for `del` appears to be updated, as well (you now pass an array of strings instead of a string by itself). More info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/del and https://gulpjs.org/recipes/handling-the-delete-event-on-watch.

Comment: Correction, the link provided by Sven is very outdated. It's also missing an IF block to test for `deleted`. Sven's code above works perfectly with the exception of `del` which has since been updated.